# Something akin to "Sparse Fieldsets" in .NET

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm trying to find the vocabulary to describe what I want and if it exists.

I have a table that shows a few data points from large objects. Loading the entire objects just for the table is very slow. Is there a way to only pass to the front the few properties I want without having to define a new object?

I found something called Sparse Fieldsets in [JSON API](https://jsonapi.org/format/#fetching-sparse-fieldsets), and I'm wondering if something like this exists for .NET under another name.

**Update:** 
Talking to another coder, I realize it probably makes more sense to implement something like this between the backend and the database and make a specific call for this table. I still need to work out if I need to create a new object to support this. I think it'd still be faster if I just kept the same object but nulled out all of the connecting objects that I don't need for the table. But maybe that's considered bad practice? Also we're using Entity Framework for what it's worth.

**Update 2:**
I just created a new query without all of the `.Include()` and works well enough for what I need:

```
_dataContext.ApplePie
.Include(f => f.Apples).ThenInclude(f => f.Apple)
        .Include(f => f.Sugars).ThenInclude(f => f.MolecularStructure)
        .Include(f => f.Recipe)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for [Anonymous Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types)?

For example, if you had a typed object with three properties, but you only wanted to operate on two:

```
var threePropThing = new ThreePropertyThing { Id = 1, Message = "test", ExtraProperty = "ex" };

var myAnonThing = new { Id = threePropThing.Id, Message = threePropThing.Message };
```

Best practice would be to not pass this anonymous object around. But, if you really needed to, you could return it as type `object`.

Typically, when passing data around in c#, you want to have it typed.

Answer (score 1):

C# is a strongly-typed language and I would say that it is unusual for C# to support scenarios, when object definition (properties) are not known in advance, like in JSON API "fields" parameter case. Implementing this would imply using reflection to filter the properties, which is usually slow and error-prone.

When implementing C# web-services, people usually create one DTO response model per each request.

If your table has fixed set of fields, I would personally recommend to create a DTO class containing only the fields which are required for your table, and then create a method which returns this response for your specific request. While it doesn't align with "without having to define a new object" in the question, it makes the intention clear and makes it really easier to maintain the API in future.

You might want to use libraries like AutoMapper to save time and avoid duplicated code of copying the values from data model to DTO, if you have many such methods.